# Sending a Search Form on mobile - keypad and / or call to action button

Tags: forms, mobile, buttons, search

say you have a modal view with a simple form and a cancel-option.
as soon as the user selects a field the keypad shows up and usually provides a "Send" or "Search" Button to send the form.

is it ok to rely on this one method/button for sending the form?
or would you add an extra call-to-action button below the form.

i think before the keypad appears a call to action button is a good way to show that you can or have to send this form. on the other hand its another UI element that takes screen-space and the users attention.

how do you layout your mobile-forms (webapp or native app)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the entry that has a specific button for sending of the form. You can call an alternate keyboard that would just have "done" or without a specific button at all. Thus forcing the user to return to the app to complete and send on a button there.

Although, you should give your user the ability to complete the form within the on screen keyboard by taping next button and then completing with a submit or post button. This will allow the user to complete their train of thought and not be deviated to go back to the form screen just to submit what they already filled out.